# SSRS White Space / Blank page Issue

Tags: reporting-services, printing, ssrs-2008-r2

I am having issues with blank pages turning up in pdfs/printing etc.

Reason seems to be the layout of my report.

I have a fixed width corporate header that fits the page. I then have a main report area with a dynamic number of columns grouped across the page.

The main report has a width of approx. 4" on the design screen, leaving a white space to the right of this of 6.5". I know that after the column groups expand out SSRS will try to render 6.5" of white space after it because that is the difference between my header (which I cannot change) and my main data area.

I understand the problem, and why it happens, that much is well documented. What I need to know if anyone has found a work around for this? I can't give management the answer "Sorry, that's the way it is."

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reports [ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.rdlobjectmodel.report.consumecontainerwhitespace(v=sql.120).aspx) property

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether all whitespace in containers, such as Body and Rectangle, should be consumed when contents grow instead of preserving the minimum white space between the contents and the container.

This can be set by clicking the Report body, going to the properties (F4) and setting `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace` to True

Comment: That's the one! Its amazing how even after using SSRS for years - you still come across little bits you've missed. Many thanks.